Prove the slope of the tangent line of $a^x$ at $(0,1)$ is $\ln{a}$.
Since the derivative is defined by
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
Then we can find the derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ as below
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{a^{x+\Delta x}-a^x}{\Delta x}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{a^x(a^{\Delta x}-1)}{\Delta x}\\
&=a^x\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{a^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}
\end{align*}
The result turns out to be the slope of the tangent line at $(0,1)$ since we can rewrite the last term as
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{a^t-1}{t-0}=f'(0)$$
So this is to say the derivative of $a^x$ is $f'(0)a^x$. But we also know the derivative of it is $\ln{a}\cdot a^x$. This is to say, $f'(0)=\ln{a}$. Why? How can we prove it?

Hint: what is the definition of $a^x$?

As far as I can interpret, your question is to prove that $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$$
For this simply use the expansion $\displaystyle{e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}}$ and use the fact that $a^x=e^{x \ln a}$

(Thanks to a commenter for pointing out the rather large error in my previous answer - I totally forgot to use the chain rule correctly!)
We can write the constant $a$ using the natural logarithmic function as $a=e^{\log_e{a}}$ and therefore $a^x=e^{x\times\log_e{a}}$
Therefore $\frac{d}{dx}(a^x)=(\log_e{a})\times e^{\log_a{x}}=\log_e{a}\times a^x$
When $x=0$ the value of the derivative is therefore $(\log_e{a})\times a^0=\log_e{a}$
As required.
